# Handling/Parsing complex nested JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Using python, Trying to parse through every key value within the dictionary. I was able to parse key value where the value is in turn another dictionary. But I'm now stuck at a point to parse a list within that inner dictionary. Below is the JSON structure.

```
json_struct = {
    "Name":"John",
    "Age":"30",
    "State":"NC",
    "xxxx":{
        "xxxx1":"1111111",
        "xxxx2":"222222",
        "xxxx3":[
            {
                "aaa1": "333",
                "aaa2":"444"
            },
            {
                "bbb1": "555",
                "bbb2":"666"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Code piece doing the iteration:

```
def check1(json_struct):
    for k, v in json_struct.items():
        if isinstance(v, OrderedDict):
            check1(v)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)
```

Actual Output:

```
Name:John
Age:30
state:NC
xxxx1:1111111
xxxx2:222222
xxxx3:[('aaa1','333'), ('aaa2':'444'), ('bbb1:555'), ('bbb2:666')]
```

Expected Output:

```
Name:John
Age:30
state:NC
xxxx1:1111111
xxxx2:222222
aaa1:333
aaa2:444
bbb1:555
bbb2:666
```

I'm missing something to iterate through the list i believe, but I tried the `isinstance` with list within the `if` as well, still the incorrect result is what I'm getting.

Any knowledge share on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues:

- you're checking for the type `OrderedDict` but this is probably specific to the version of Python you're using; on Python 3.x you'd check for `dict` instead;
- the `aaa1` and similar values are inside of a list, between `[]` and that's what you're seeing as the output.

This is what you'd do to check for that too:

```
def check1(json_struct):
    for k, v in json_struct.items():
        if isinstance(v, OrderedDict):
            check1(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for e in v:
                check1(e)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)
```

You may need `dict` instead of `OrderedDict`, when using versions of Python 3.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. And the reason for `OrderedDict` is to maintain the order of similar to key/value in JSON. Using `dict`, changes the order in the result set. But yes when I use dict, it works fine but it is just that order is changes. Another quick question, When iterating through list within dict, there are some unicode values(not key/value). i.e `{'"a":{"b":["0","1"]}}`. This results in an error "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items". Trying to find a specific function or check to handle this case.

Comment: Do you need to use Python 2? Because using Unicode is a *lot* simpler in Python 3 and your code would probably be fairly simple to update to work with Python 3 as well. If you do need Python 2, I don't understand your example, it seems to be missing a `'` and the error message seems to suggest the `json_struct` you're passing in is a Unicode string `unicode`, instead of an `OrderedDict`?

Comment: Yes Grismar! I'll be sticking to 2.7 for this use case. Ignore the previous example, consider the below 
`{
"X":"Text1",
"Y":"Text2",
"a":{
     "b":["0","1"]
}
}`
X and Y are parsed but when its comes to b, the code fails with "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'items".
I also tried this, just to check how the code behaves,(not sure if it makes any difference)
`{
"X":"Text1",
"Y":"Text2",
"b":["0","1"]
}`
It is the same error. But now it fails immediately. Does not parse through X and Y.

Comment: The error about not having an attribute `items` would be because whatever gets passed in is not a `dict` (or `OrderedDict`). In your case, it seems like you're passing in a Unicode string. Can you please update your original question with a clear example that has this behaviour? Because from what you're saying and from the code I provided, I cannot reproduce your issue.